# Querying Oracle Datawarehouse Via ODBC driver using Microsoft Excel 2007

Tags: excel, oracle

I'm trying to pass two date parameters through to a query in Microsoft Excel.

The query works perfectly fine when the command text is as follows:

```
SELECT TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE, TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_SCATEGORY,
       TINVOICETEMPLATEFIELDCATEGORY.IFC_SDESCRIPTION,
       TINVOICE.INV_CUS_LKEY, TCUSTOMER.CUS_SNUMBER,        
       TCUSTOMER.CUS_SNAME, TINVOICE.INV_LNUMBER, 
       TINVOICE.INV_AGR_LKEY, TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_FLINETOTAL

FROM PROD.TCUSTOMER TCUSTOMER, PROD.TINVOICE TINVOICE, 
     PROD.TINVOICEDETAIL TINVOICEDETAIL, 
     PROD.TINVOICETEMPLATEFIELDCATEGORY TINVOICETEMPLATEFIELDCATEGORY

WHERE TCUSTOMER.CUS_LKEY = TINVOICE.INV_CUS_LKEY 
  AND TINVOICE.INV_LKEY = TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_INV_LKEY 
  AND TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_SCATEGORY = TINVOICETEMPLATEFIELDCATEGORY.IFC_SCODE 
  AND ((TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE>= {ts '2015-02-01 00:00:00'}) 
  AND (TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE< {ts '2016-02-01 00:00:00'}) 
  AND (TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_SCATEGORY<>'GS28') 
  AND (TINVOICE.INV_LNUMBER<>0) 
  AND (TINVOICEDETAIL.IDE_FLINETOTAL<>0))
ORDER BY TINVOICE.INV_LNUMBER
```

but when I drop in parameters by exchanging these blocks {ts '2015-02-01 00:00:00'} for these '?' it throws an error. I've played around with a number of solutions and none seem to work, or I'm not implementing them correctly. When I query the databases NLS properties it returns the following:

```
PARAMETER                VALUE
NLS_LANGUAGE             ENGLISH
NLS_TERRITORY            UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_CURRENCY             £
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY         UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS   .,
NLS_CALENDAR             GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT          DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE        ENGLISH
NLS_SORT                 BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT          HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT     DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT       HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT  DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY        €
NLS_COMP                 BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS     BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP      FALSE
```

If anyone could help I'd be really appreciative! and can give more information if required!

Thanks!

Comment: So what is the error??

Comment: It depends on how I've tried to insert the parameter. If I do it with a date such as '01/02/2015' (1st of Feb) I get '[Oracle][ODBC]{Ora]ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month'.  If I try formatting a date with the following excel formula: TEXT(B4,"mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss") I get the following error: '[Oracle][ODBC]{Ora]ORA-01843: not a valid month.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here, but the {ts } construct is specific to ODBC/JDBC, and so it may be that mixing this with the variable binding in native oracle is causing the issues. Why not try switching that out for Oracle's native to_timestamp function instead?

```
 AND ((TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE>= to_timestamp(?,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') ) 
  AND (TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE< to_timestamp(?,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Although also check and ensure that the field is a timestamp and not a date (you don't have fractional seconds in your formatted string) in which case to_Date would be more appropriate.

Comment: When I change the query to this:          ((TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE>= to_date(?,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')) AND (TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE< to_date(?,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'))     I'm getting this error [Oracle][ODBC]{Ora]ORA-01862: Literal does not match format string.     If I use timestamp instead I get the error ORA-1862: the numeric value does not match the length of the format item.

Comment: What is the exact string you are passing in? This string has to match the format mask, so you can adjust the format mask to match whowever your data is formatted... See here for available options: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: It now works!  I'm using this in the query: (TINVOICE.INV_DINVOICEDATE>= to_date(?,'YYYY-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS'))    And I'm using this in excel for the parameter:    =TEXT(INDEX(Lists!$A$3:$A$14,MATCH($B$3&$B$2,Lists!$P$3:$P$14,0),1),"YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I've wasted so much time on it. I figured it would be a problem with the format, but wasn't sure if it required me to fix the query or in excel or with a combination of the two (it was the latter). and felt like I was going round in circles. You've been a massive help!